# SharePoint List/Ticketing System- How to keep reply emails under the same Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, automation

I recently just created a SharePoint list which I will be using as a ticketing system.

The idea is when we get an email send to "Ticket@outlook.com.au" it will produce an item in my SharePoint list (ticketing system).

I have achieved this fine using power automate (following this guys YouTube)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS6KzlcRfU0

However I am wanting to put all the reply emails in the same item.

Instead I am getting new items for each reply email which is no good.

Does it have this functionally?

This is my workflow

[image]

I've tried the workflow below but am stuck on 2 sections as indicated below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conversation Id from the response which you can store into list as well, because for Reply email Conversation Id will be same as previous one.

Before adding Item you can do REST call to Ticket List whether any item is exist by Conversation Id or not, and if exist then you can update your existing item.

[image]

[image]

Hope it will helpful to you.

For Parse JSON, First you can call your SharePoint API via postman and then you can click on "Generate Sample" and paste JSON reply which you get from postman tool.

After then in condition, and update item action you can use output from Parse JSON action.

[image]

Another approach which you can use that is described here.. https://tomriha.com/get-data-from-http-response-without-parse-json-in-power-automate/

Comment: Hi, im stuck on the Parse JSON (Parse Response - Purple Box) What do i populated in the content and schema?

Comment: I'll post my workflows in the question so you can see. One is my original workflow and second is my attempt of yours

Comment: I have updated my answer for parse json